# SQL-How to Convert string to timestamp (DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS to timestamp)

Tags: hana, sap-business-technology-platform

I am using SAP HANA BTP-SQL.

I have a order table with a column CREATED_DATETIME . Datatype is varchar (date format is not standard-so datatype fixed as string). Would like to convert it to timestamp
in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'.
Since I am beginner , please help with script to convert from string to timestamp.
Tried below scripts- getting error-please help me to convert to timestamp:

```
created_datetime           Expected timestamp
01-09-2022  11:50:34       2022-09-01 00:00:00
```

This order table,column created_datetime value has 01-09-2022  11:50:34.Still unable to convert.

I have to convert all the records from created_datetime column to timestamp in the format 2022-09-01 00:00:00

Tried below scripts- getting error-please help me to convert to timestamp:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (CREATED_DATETIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') FROM ORDER_TABLE;
```

> error: (dberror) [303]: invalid DATE, TIME or TIMESTAMP value: SQL Error

```
SELECT TO_DATE (CREATED_DATETIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') from ORDER_TABLE;
```

> error: (dberror) [303]: invalid DATE, TIME or TIMESTAMP value: SQL Error

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE (CREATED_DATETIME,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') from ORDER_TABLE;
```

> (dberror) [328]: invalid name of function or procedure: STR_TO_DATE

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CREATED_DATETIME, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')) from ORDER_TABLE;
```

> (dberror) [328]: invalid name of function or procedure: UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Comment: which databse system are actually using convertint string to datetime is very rdms dependent

Answer (score 0):

if your date is `01-09-2022  11:50:34`

you need the same format as the original data

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (CREATED_DATETIME,'DD-MM-YYYY H24:MI:SS') FROM ORDER_TABLE;
```

Comment: Date is in the format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss- 01-09-2022  11:50:34 (this is string). Required to convert this in to timestamp of format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. (2022-09-01 11:50:34)

Comment: the default format is yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm_ss for a timestampand the function converts a string to that format as long as you haven't change the date time format with DATE_FORMAT or TIME_FORMAT, if you have done that you should change it back as you want that format, so run the code and see what you get

Comment: Hours is HH24 and Minutes is MI, not MM (this is month). 
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (CREATED_DATETIME,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM ORDER_TABLE;